# Jquery animate height change with a button

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

Basically what I'm doing is making a "view more" type of thing. I have a small paragraph of text describing something that I've worked on, and a button at the end of the paragraph. I (It's really a link, with a button style).  When the button is pressed the div expands to 400px, and extra text is added with .html(); but when I hit the "view less" button to collapse back to the smaller paragraph, and 200px div, nothing happens.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $mottheight = $('#row-mott').height();

if ( $mottheight == 300 ) {
    $('#mott-btn-collapse').click(function(){
    $('#row-mott').animate({
        height:200
    }, 300);
    $('#mott').html('I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. <a href="#" id="mott-btn" class="btn btn-mini">Less info &raquo</a>');

});
}
else if ( $mottheight < 300 ){
    $('#mott-btn').click(function(){
    $('#row-mott').animate({
        height:300
    }, 400);
    $('#mott').html('I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. <a href="#" id="mott-btn-collapse" class="btn btn-mini">Less info &raquo</a>');
    });
}
else {
    return 0;
}
});
```

Comment: Remember that the code is executed at load time.  When the page loads the first if statement is false, so the click binding never gets loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is very awkwardly coded. You need to capture the height within the function, rather than just at page load, and you can combine all click items.

```
var $row_mott = $('#row-mott'),
    $mott = $('#mott');

$('#mott-btn-collapse').click(function(){
    var $mottheight = $row_mott.height();

    if ($mottheight == 300) {
        $row_mott.stop().animate({height:200}, 300);
        $mott.html('I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. <a href="#" id="mott-btn" class="btn btn-mini">Less info &raquo</a>');
    } else if ($mottheight < 300){
        $row_mott.stop().animate({height:300}, 400);
        $mott.html('I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott High School website since September of 2011. I am one of four student webmasters that keep the website in the best condition possible. We cannot take credit for all the coding, though. This website is run by around 40 Web Design students. As Webmaster, my job is to fix, improve, and help those students learn as they go. <a href="#" id="mott-btn-collapse" class="btn btn-mini">Less info &raquo</a>');
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**

- I converted your selectors into variables cached; its good practice when using the selector multiple times
- I added `.stop()` prior to your animations, to prevent excess queuing
- I consolidated the action into a single button; this is more personal preference, but for a more consistent user experience having a single "Expand/Collapse" button is pretty standardized

Comment: This is what I was trying to do in my answer as well except I made it even more awkward than the original so I just deleted it. Nice work. +1 Buddy :)

Comment: I'm currently away from my PC, but when I get back I'll try this out. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're only running the click handlers once. So, upon document load it finds the #row-mott height, sets it, and evaluates what you have. By default, it's < 300. You need to check the height inside the click event, not before.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $mottheight = $('#row-mott').height();
    $('#mott-btn-collapse').click(function(){
       if ( $mottheight == 300 ) {
     $('#row-mott').animate({
            height:200
        }, 300);
        $('#mott').html('I\'ve worked on the W...</a>');

    });
    }else if($mottheight < 300 ){
        $('#mott-btn').click(function(){
        $('#row-mott').animate({
            height:300
        }, 400);
        $('#mott').html('I\'ve worked on the Warren Mott....they go. <a href="#" id="mott-btn-collapse" class="btn btn-mini">Less info &raquo</a>');
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was extremely simple and I honestly don't know why I didn't think of this before.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#mott-appended').hide();
   $('#patrick-appended').hide();

   /* Start Warren Mott High School text show/hide */

   $('#mott-btn').click(function(){
    $('#mott-appended').show('slow');
    $(this).hide('slow');
   });

   $('#mott-btn-collapse').click(function(){
    $('#mott-appended').hide('slow');
    $('#mott-btn').show('slow');
   });

   /* End Warren Mott High School text show/hide */
   /* Start Patrick Studios text show/hide */

    $('#patrick-btn').click(function(){
       $('#patrick-appended').show('slow');
       $(this).hide('slow');
    });

    $('#patrick-btn-collapse').click(function(){
       $('#patrick-appended').hide('slow');
       $('#patrick-btn').show('slow');
   });

   /* End Patrick Studios text show/hide */

});
```